# Appcelerator. Detect click on navbar title

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app in Appcelerator. How can I detect when the user taps the title of the window (the title in the navbar)?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would place a transparent view over the navBar title... that is the easiest solution if you are not using a title control.

Comment: I am using this: window.titleControl = title_view; Is there another way? How can I place a view in the navbar if I am not using title control?